# From 'one behind' to 'one before' (between)

Tags: javascript, regex

In the string below, I want to find, for example, everything between '[' and 'A'.
Here 'match1', 'match2', 'match3'. And than replace every match with, for example, 'check'.

```
var str = "+dkdele*[match1Ayesses ss [match2Aevey[match3A";
var pattern = /(?=\[)(.*?)([]?A)/g; // includes '[' and 'A'
var res = str.replace(pattern, "check"); // could be '[checkA'
console.log(res);
```

The pattern includes '[' and 'A', what I **don't** want. How could a pattern look like, which matches **between** two any desired *signs*?

Comment: Note that anubhava's answer also provides a useful site where you can  test RegEx code: [Regular Expression 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I know this site. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var pattern     = /(\[).*?(A)/g;
var replacement = "check";
var res         = str.replace( pattern, '$1' + replacement + '$2' );
```

The regular expression is:

- `(\[)` - match an open square bracket and capture the match in a the first group.
- `.*?` - match the minimum possible of zero-or-more of any characters
- `(A)` - then match an `A` and capture it in the second group.

The replacement will put in the first and second capture groups instead of `$1` and `$2` (respectively).

With any start and end matches you can do:

```
var start       = "\\[";
var end         = "A";
var pattern     = new RegExp( "(" + start + ").*?(" + end + ")", "g" );
var replacement = "check";
var res         = str.replace( pattern, '$1' + replacement + '$2' );
```

If you don't want to include the start and end match characters then don't include the capture groups in the replacement:

```
var res         = str.replace( pattern, replacement );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
/\[(\w+)(?=A)/g
```

and grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/1)

If there can be more than word characters then use:

```
/\[([^A]+)(?=A)/g
```

---

**Code:**

```
var re = /\[([^A]+)(?=A)/g; 
var str = '+dkdele*[match1Ayesses ss [match2Aevey[match3A';
var m;    
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
match1
match2
match3
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on edited question and comment below:

For replacement you can use:

```
var repl = str.replace(/(\[)[^A]+(?=A)/, '$1check');
//=> +dkdele*[checkAyesses ss [checkAevey[checkA
```

PS: If you want `A` also to be replaced then use:

```
var repl = str.replace(/(\[)[^A]+A/, '$1check');
//=> +dkdele*[checkyesses ss [checkevey[check
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have forgotten to say, that I want to replace the match. The question is edited.